# How to best generate keys for objects not being store in db?

Tags: java

If I have some object with some properties that changes. How can I best track the object? Probably creating an ID. What might be useful for creating such an id? A static field that is counted up on creation?

```
class Foo {
  String bar;
  int id;

  static int counter = 0;

  Foo() {
    this.id = counter++;
  }
}
```

Could I do better?
I do not want to store the objects in db, and I do not want to use a HashMap or thelike.

Comment: http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=56

Comment: I know UUID. But is that 100% save? I mean, of course it's unlikely that an UUID is double generated. Buf if at anytime this happens though, that would be a desaster. So using UUID, I'd have to consequently make iterations through all objects on creation if no other object already contains that UUID, to be 100% sure. Think that's very inefficient.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UUID#Random_UUID_probability_of_duplicates

Comment: the probability of generated UUIDs colliding is very very small. I doubt you would ever encounter such a case. [UUID Collision Probability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Random_UUID_probability_of_duplicates)

Comment: One may argue that it's more likely to encounter an integer (or even long) overflow (and collisions) than to encounter collisions for UUIDs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For single threaded applications your approach is OK. For multithreaded you could use

```
 AtomicInteger idGen  = new AtomicInteger();
```

to get the next Id you would invoke:

```
idGen.getAndIncrement();
```

[JavaDoc AtomicInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html)